# CSS class disappears when the parent jsp loads

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, jsp

I am having a jsp file which gets loaded after the index.jsp file. I have added a css class name for the body tag of index.jsp and also a css class name for it's child jsp's body tag.

**index.jsp (parent jsp):-**

```
<body id="siteBody" class="tundra parentCssProps">
...
...
```

**preLoader.jsp (child jsp):-**

```
<body class="loaderCssProps">
...
...
```

My issue in here is, the css class name (`loaderCssProps`) of the child jsp gets replaced by the index.jsp (which is the parent) css class names (`tundra parentCssProps`). Child jsp's body tag looks like below, when inspecting by using firebug. Due to this none of the style I have added to `loaderCssProps` gets applied.

**preLoader.jsp (child jsp):-**

```
<body id="siteBody" class="tundra parentCssProps">
```

This looks like all the attributes of the parent jsp body tag is replacing the child jsp. Appreciate your support on this to overcome the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: why do you use body multiple times?

Comment: having an iframe. child jsp is loaded into the iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery to add a class.

That would be-

```
$( "body" ).addClass( "loaderCssProps" );
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: I found the problem. Parent JSP was using dojo to manipulate html body tags. So its content overrides the child jsp's body tag. Your suggestion became helpful to solve the issue. But this time I didn't use jquery to add the class. Instead, I used dojo.addClass(win.body(),"loaderCssProps"). Thnx for the suggestion @Pav.